# How to write a batch file that simply writes the given parameters into a file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, text, cmd

I need to make a batch file that receives 3 parameters (let's call them `p1`, `p2` and `p3`) and writes them line by line in a new file in the user Desktop folder (that last part is important)

Expected usage:
`D:\Temp\WriteFile -p1=aaa -p2=bbb -p3=ccc`

Output in `C:\User\Desktop\output.txt` (or wherever the user desktop folder might be):

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

What I'm more concerned about is to find the current user Desktop folder and write the file there.

Comment: You should not have any problems finding the desktop folder. The user profile is a system environmental variable. Open up a cmd prompt and type: set. It will show you all the system variables you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're trying to pass parameters incorrectly. The Windows standard for batch files is not to name the parameters, but just pass them directly on the command line (example below).

Second, the user's Desktop folder is found in `%USERPROFILE%`, in the Desktop subfolder (again, example below).

This will write the content you want into the current user's Desktop folder, in a file named `testdesktop.txt`. The first line creates the file and writes the first parameter passed as line one. The other lines append the successive parameters to the same file. The double quotes around the output filename handle user names that have spaces (e.g., "John Smith"), where the desktop folder would be `C:\Users\John Smith\Desktop`.

Save this content into a batch file - for demo purposes, let's call that `MakeDesktopFile.bat`, and the file it creates `testdesktop.txt`.

```
@echo off
echo %1 > "%userprofile%\Desktop\testdesktop.txt"
echo %2 >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\testdesktop.txt"
echo %3 >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\testdesktop.txt"
```

Call it like this:

```
MakeDesktopFile aa bb cc
```

The output:

```
C:\>type %userprofile%\Desktop\testdesktop.txt
aa
bb
cc

C:\>
```

Comment: Thank you! yes, this seems the simplest solution to my problem. Which is already very simple but I have no experience with Windows scripting.

Comment: It may be the simplest solution to you @odiseo, but it unfortunately only works for some users, _hence the reason why two of the answers used more robust methodology_.

Comment: @Compo: Nonsense. The %USERPROFILE% exists in all versions of Windows since Win95, it's set by the OS at login, and it's accurate even with roaming profiles or non-default profile settings. Your answer (which you seem to have no problem touting in a comment to mine) is overly complex, especially for the needs described in this question.

Comment: @KenWhite, please take a look at my response to your comment below my answer, please also note that my comment above was specifically to the OP, not directly to you. As far as I'm aware there's no rule or guidance on this site suggesting that I cannot do so.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to get the location of the Desktop is from the registry:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" GoTo Next
Set "SF=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "HKCU\%SF%" /V Desktop') Do (
    For %%C In (%*) Do Echo %%~C)>"%%~B\output.txt"
:Next
```

You would run this script, `WriteFile.cmd`, like this:

```bat
D:\Temp\WriteFile aaa bbb ccc
```

If any of the parameters contain spaces or problematic characters like **`, ; =`** you should surround them with doublequotes:

```bat
D:\Temp\WriteFile "aa a" "b,bb" "cc;c" "d=dd"
```

Comment: This answer, while it may work, is technically incorrect. The registry is not the proper location to find the desktop folder, especially from a batch file. You're also calling an external application (reg.exe) on every single iteration through the loop.The OS provides the %USERPROFILE% variable for that purpose for use in scripts, and an API call to find it from an application's code. The registry is no more *safe* than either of those alternatives, and your answer is no more *robust* than the one I posted.

Comment: @KenWhite, it is not uncommon for a user to redirect their `Desktop` folder to another location, when they do so `%UserProfile%` remains where it was, and `%UserProfile%\Desktop` no longer refers to the users redirected location, _unless a junction is created there to compensate_. When the 'shell folder' is redirected, the registry is updated to the new location, hence the reason for this methodology. You may also note that I never said that it was the 'proper location', _neither in my answer nor my comment, I said it was safer and more robust, than `%UserProfile%\Desktop` as explained above.

Comment: @KenWhite, if you take a look at the code above, you'll also note that  `Reg.exe` is ran only once, there's only one iteration. Your method opens and closes the text file more than once, mine doesn't, so I doubt that there's any real speed impact from using `Reg.exe` once in comparison.

Comment: You're right in one regard. Reg.exe is in fact only called once, so I was mistaken. The rest is still true, however. Redirection to a text file a dozen times will still be more efficient than using reg.exe, which not only launches the executable but then has to make API calls to read the registry hive. If a user chooses to redirect their user profile to another location, that's fine. The proper location to place the file would then be in the Desktop folder under that profile folder.

Comment: @KenWhite, I have redirected shell folders on many PC's before, _usually to a different drive_. I know for a fact that when doing so `%UserProfile%\Desktop` no longer refers to the location, as does Michael Heath. did you really believe that we both came up with essentially the same methodology, because we were oblivious the `%UserProfile%` variable?

Comment: I think you've both seen the reg.exe solution here before (as I have) and decided to attempt to apply that overkill solution to this much more straightforward question. That two people decide to choose the same overly complex solution to a simple question isn't uncommon here. It happens all the time. It doesn't make that automatically correct or better. A frequent occurrence here is for someone to ask a relatively simple question about string manipulation where someone will write an extremely complex regex-based answer when a simple IndexOf would be more appropriate.

Comment: @KenWhite, I certainly wouldn't copy someone elses idea on StackOverflow. Had I seen it here, I'd have included it in a comment, or even flagged it as a duplicate. The OP specifically said, **wherever the user desktop folder might be**, you answer caters only for the default location, you may not like that fact, but it's true. You can call our answers overly complex if you like, I cannot object to your opinion, but my answer works and is more robust because it more closely caters for the actual question. I accept that the OP probably only needed the default location but future readers may not!

Comment: I didn't say *copy someone else's idea*. I said *a solution you've seen elsewhere*, just to make that clear. I certainly see no reason to overly complicate a very simple solution. *I need to cross over this brook.* "Ok, first hire an engineer, have them draw up the specifications. Make sure they allow for a future crossing by heavy equipment or a tank in case of war Then hire an architect to actually design the structure. Then hire a contractor to come in and do the work." Or you could just lay a couple of planks down, walk across and be done with it. I opt for the latter myself.

Comment: @KenWhite, you see no reason to opt for an engineer because you won't accept the advice of someone who's lived in area and knows that the environment can, and does, change. On a usual day, you'll end up on terra firma, but when you end up in the drink you'll realise that my bridge was the safer and more robust solution.

Comment: Except I've lived in this area far longer than everyone else here, and I know the terrain and environment very well. It's you new folks that just moved here that don't understand the locality. There's absolutely no reason to pay for that engineer. Do you pay for someone to build a structure for you to get across a puddle as well? If so, you're either bankrupt or soggy.

Comment: @KenWhite, I have lived in the area of redirected shell folders, had you done so, perhaps you'd be less blinkered. Instead of trying to deflect from your failure to accept that my methodology is safer/more robust, try proving that it isn't. _(Perhaps you could redirect your `Desktop` folder, test it with `"%UserProfile%\Desktop"` then return here to make your argument)_. I have told you why I used this methodology, your failure to accept it, doesn't make it wrong; showing that my methodolgy is flawed, however may.

Comment: @Campo: So have I. I've been dealing with the shell and it's intricacies since Windows 3, and DOS long before that time. Those redirection cases occur. However, they're very few and far between, and overengineering for the remotely possible case (especially when writing an answer for a less experienced user) is ridiculous. Note too that for the second time, you're falsely accusing me of words I never wrote. I didn't say your answer was *wrong*, just overly complicated for the situation described and individual posting here.

Comment: @KenWhite, when making an argument, it helps that the information you are basing it on is correct. I said that you were saying my methodology was wrong, not my answer. _You said that my answer worked but was technically incorrect. I said that my answer was safer and more robust, and have fully explained the technical reason for it. Back up your statement, why is it technically incorrect? It is the only way you can win this argument. You appear above to have accepted that my answer works in the case of a redirected shell folder, you just need to accept that yours doesn't, and we're done!_

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%A in (%*) do call :args %%A

echo p1=%p1% p2=%p2% p3=%p3%

call :shellfolder desktop
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1

(
    echo Desktop: "%desktop%"
    echo p1: %p1%
    echo p2: %p2%
    echo p3: %p3%
) > "%desktop%\output.txt"

exit /b

:args
set arg=%~1
if "%arg:~,1%" == "-" set "prefix=%arg:~1%" & exit /b
set %prefix%=%arg%
exit /b

:shellfolder
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
    'reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "%~1"'
) do if /i "%%~A" == "%~1" set "%~1=%%~C"
exit /b
```

The users desktop is a *Shell Folder* so it may not be in the user profile
folder. Some registry reading is needed the get the location.

**A description of the script above:**

The script arguments are passed to the 1st for loop with each argument
delimited by the `=` character as well as the usual space character.
The called `:args` label assigns the argument passed to `arg`.
If the 1st character is `-`, then it is set to `prefix`, otherwise
it will set `%prefix%=%arg%` where `%prefix%` is the argument
prefix name i.e. `p1`.

The called `:shellfolder` label accepts the value of the Shell Folder
as an argument.
A `reg query` in the `for` loop gets the data value of the Shell Folder
and sets the argument name to the data value.
No explicit `errorlevel` is set using i.e. `exit /b 1` as the errorlevel
from `reg query` may be suitable enough. A check of `errorlevel` is done
after the `:shellfolder` call to ensure it is safe to continue.

If success, then it will write `output.txt` to the users desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to use a for loop. it is not dependant on the number of arguments, it can be 3 or 5 etc.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (%*) do (
    echo %%i >> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt"
)
```

If you want to however rewrite the output each time you run it, then just empty the file.

```
@echo off
type > nul "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt"
for %%i in (%*) do (
    echo %%i >> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt"
)
```